# "OneDrive for Business Next Generation Sync Client" installs incorrectly

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I downloaded and ran the installer from here

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Transition-from-the-previous-OneDrive-for-Business-sync-client-4100df3a-0c96-464f-b0a8-c20de34da6fa?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

It completed without error, but launching onedrive for business still runs groove.exe (it should be onedrive.exe, it says so on the same site). Also, onedrive.exe cannot be found on C:\

EDIT

Correction; onedrive.exe is on C:\, launches, and goes through the configuration process as described. However, GROOVE.EXE still launches in the background! Should this be happening? If I read it correctly, only onedrive.exe should launch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to suspect that groove.exe is being launched by chrome to handle onedrive links. Will confirm shortly.